# Can the Switch split a downloaded game between internal storage and SD card?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I'm planning to install Apex Legends on my Nintendo Switch tomorrow, but when I looked at the space requirements on the eshop page, I noticed it needs 20GB of free storage.  I have 32GB of internal storage and a 16GB SD card.  I moved everything I can to the SD card and deleted the rest of the software on internal storage.  I also moved all of the screenshots to my computer.  I still only have 17.9 GB free on my internal storage, but I also have 3GB free on my SD card.

My question then is will I need to buy another SD card, or will the Switch download 17GB to the internal storage and 3GB to the SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got no sources but since splitting the game in half on PC is hard if not impossible, and that would be with the full control a PC provides, I would guess the same is true on Switch.

So if you want to download Apex (or any game) on your Switch or on an SD Card, you must have that space available, in one chunk, on the Switch or the SD Card.

It is impossible to split the game between two different elements.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info!  I'll wait to see if a better answer shows up, but if not, I'll mark yours as the answer.  It just seems weird to me that a game wouldn't work without buying extra hardware.

Comment: Hell, I would love to have Apex on both my PC's hard drive, and it pulls the elements from whichever one is not occupied at the moment. I really wonder how the switch will run Apex, its not the easiest game to run. Hell, the Xbox One fell flat on their faces trying to have PUBG running on hardware that is probably more potent than the switch, especially the switch in handheld mode.

Comment: Yeah I wonder how well it will run as well.  I have a pc with a 2060 so I don't *need* it on the Switch, but it would be nice to have when I'm on campus and don't have my desktop.

Comment: If I had Nintendo Online I would give it a DL just to see how that runs.

Comment: I'm not sure it even takes Switch Online.  I'll give it a try tomorrow when it comes out if it will download.

Comment: Well, I didn't buy a SD card for my switch so I'm stuck there too. But hey, I got you that can test it and tell us how that runs.

Comment: If I get an SD card that's big enough lol

Answer (score 0):

Whelp I guess this is pretty self explanatory.

[image: this]